# can not add ARG as an argument to CMD in Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

I want to send an argument to a dockerfile and send it to a script as an argument. so I build the docker like this:

```
docker build --build-arg x=somedata .
```

on the dockerfile I write something like:

```
CMD ["python3", "script.py", ???]
```

When I run the container I want the following to be run:

```
python3 script.py somedata
```

how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the argument when you run the container.

```bash
docker run your-image \
  python3 script.py somedata
```

```yaml
# or in docker-compose.yml
command: python3 script.py somedata
```

If you'll be doing this frequently, there is a pattern of using the image's `ENTRYPOINT` as the command to run and its `CMD` as its argument;

```bash
# Dockerfile
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "script.py"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

```bash
docker run your-image \
  somedata
```

In all cases, this command replaces the image's `CMD`, and is appended to the `ENTRYPOINT` if present.  If you're using the `ENTRYPOINT`-as-command pattern then both the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` lines must use the JSON-array "exec form" syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I had used environment variables as a way to pass arguments to scripts